# Install GSLL on SBCL with Quicklisp

Tags: common-lisp, gsl, sbcl, quicklisp

I am trying to install the GNU Scientific Library for Lisp (GSLL).
I saw there are answers to a similar question already, but I didn't find the connection to what is happening in my case.

Could anyone help to move on from here?

```
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-type)
"SBCL"
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-version)
"1.2.4.debian"

CL-USER> (ql:quickload "gsll")

; cc -m64 -I/lrde/home/alandi/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.14.0/ -o /lrde/home/alandi/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.2.4.debian-linux-x64/lrde/home/alandi/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.14.0/libffi/libffi-unix /lrde/home/alandi/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.2.4.debian-linux-x64/lrde/home/alandi/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.14.0/libffi/libffi-unix.c
; 

; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 2 fatal ERROR conditions

To load "gsll":
  Load 8 ASDF systems:
    alexandria antik asdf-system-connections cffi-grovel
    cffi-libffi metabang-bind osicat trivial-garbage

  Install 1 Quicklisp gsll
    release:
; Loading "gsll"

; cc -m64 -I/lrde/home/alandi/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.14.0/ -o /lrde/home/alandi/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.2.4.debian-linux-x64/lrde/home/alandi/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.14.0/libffi/libffi-unix /lrde/home/alandi/.cache/common-lisp/sbcl-1.2.4.debian-linux-x64/lrde/home/alandi/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.14.0/libffi/libffi-unix.c

; 
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 2 fatal ERROR conditions
; Evaluation aborted on Component "gsll" not found.
```

Comment: This looks a lot like you have an issue with the C compilation. Try running the command `cc -m64 ...` on the command line and paste it into the error description. My innocent guess is that you're missing some C dependency (library and/or headers) for compilation.

Answer (score 2):

I am on OS X, but maybe this helps you anyway. I could load the lib by `(ql:quickload "gsll")` but I had to make an adjustment:

The path to GSLs dynamic libraries is found by a shell call `gsl-config --prefix`.

For me this call returns `/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.16` but my dynlibs are located in `/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.16/lib`. So I just had to make some adjustments to the pathnames in the file `~/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/gsll-20140211-git/init/init.lisp`.

Seach for `(cffi:define-foreign-library libgslcblas ...)` and `(cffi:define-foreign-library libgsl ...)` and adjust your paths there.

Maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks Frank. That was it.